# How to put sub-routine inside VUE method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to put sub-routing inside a VUE method for handle repeatably calculation

say :

```
methods :{
 testme(total){
    function addition(total)
      return total++
    };
    function subtraction(total)
      return total--
    };
    this.totalValue[add]=addition(total)
    this.totalValue[sub]=subtraction(total)
},
```

I make a few search, not fund similar code, also try with VUE but the this.totalValue get undefined error.

Comment: where do you define `totalValue`? please share more code

Comment: Why not declare addition and subtraction outside of `testme()`?